# Is it correct to move the navigation bar frame?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I have a navigation bar based ipad app.

At some point I want to push another view controller into the views controller hierarchy. Then, when the users tabs some button I want to show a leftMenu controller. To do so I have two views:

A content view which has all the content

And a not visible view which is the leftMenu. This one is under the content view.

So when the user presses the button, what Im doing right now is moving the content view and the navigation bar to the right to make the leftMenu visible:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(271.0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);

    
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(271.0, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height);
```

This is working, but the first row in the left menu is not "clickable" where the nav bar is supossed to be. Its like the navigation bar is still there capturing the tab events.

Is it correct to do?:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(271.0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
```

If not, whats the propper way to achieve what I want?

Heres and image ilustrating what the problem is:

[image: example]

Comment: I suggest you do it using DDMenuController.. if you're trying to show and hide the leftMenu (just like in the Facebook Mobile app).. or even Path application..

Comment: Id like to do it on my own, that can´t be that difficult. (nut gonna check the source code)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to use a custom container controller to do this kind of thing, rather than moving a navigation bar. In IB, this can be set up quite easily. Start with a UIViewController, add a container view to it, and size how you want. Then in the inspector, set its x value to minus its width, which will put it off screen to the left. Then add another   container view and size it to be full screen. You can then delete the view controller that you got with that container view, and right drag from the container view to your initial navigation controller (of your already setup UI) to connect it up with an embed segue. The UIViewController that you started with should be made the initial view controller of the storyboard. To move in the side view, I use this code in that custom container controller:

```
-(void)slideInLeft {
    if (isRevealed == NO) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
            leftView.center = CGPointMake(leftView.center.x + 100, leftView.center.y);
            mainView.center = CGPointMake(mainView.center.x + 100, mainView.center.y);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            isRevealed = YES; ;
        }];
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
            leftView.center = CGPointMake(leftView.center.x - 100, leftView.center.y);
            mainView.center = CGPointMake(mainView.center.x - 100, mainView.center.y);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            isRevealed = NO;
        }];
    }

}
```

leftView and mainView are IBOutlets to the 2 container views. I call this method from a button in the main view controller (the root view controller of the navigation controller that's embedded in the large container view):

```
-(IBAction)callSlideIn:(id)sender {
    [(ViewController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController slideInLeft];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a "fast" way to achieve this (and a bit hacky imo)

I added the leftMenu view to the top view in the views hierachy:

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window)
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];

[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.leftMenu.view];
```

Now it is les deep than the navigation bar and, of course, its clickable